# class and private variables

Tags: python

```
class Test1:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.__test = 1
    def getvalue( self ):
        return self.__test

class Test2( Test1 ):
    def __init__( self ):
        Test1.__init__( self )
        self.__test = 2

test = Test2()
```

Why print test.getvalue() return 1 ?

Comment: This wouldn't work in any OO language. If `Test1` has a private variable, `Test2` does not have access to it. Protected variables are hidden from other classes, but exposed to child classes.

Comment: And **this** is why you don't use name mangling for private variables.

Answer (score 9):

In Python, private member `__bar` of class `Foo` will be [automatically renamed](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) to `_Foo__bar`, so the `__test` in `Test1` is `_Test1__test` and that in `Test2` is `_Test2__test`. The two members are actually different. This is *by design*, to ["avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private).

Use a single underscore `_test` if you want the subclass to see the variable while still want to keep it not part of the public interface.

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is due to the [name mangling for attribute names starting with `__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).  Basically, `__test` gets mangled to `_Test1__test` inside `Test1` and to `_Test2__test` inside `Test2`, so they are two different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the same way in other languages, such as Java (try it!)

```
class Test1 {
    private int test = 1;
    public int getValue() {
        return test;
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test1 {
    private int test = 2;
}

public class Test { // Run the test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        System.out.println(t.getValue());
    }
}
```

*(Why am I posting Java code in a Python-related question? Because some comments say that “this wouldn't work in any OO language” and “this is why you don't use name mangling for private variables” — Java takes another approach to OO compared to Python, and doesn't use name-mangling for private variables, yet the behavior is the same)*

A method declared in Test1 has access to Test1's private variables. Whether the method is called from a child class won't change anything, unless the child class overrides the method. It's not that private members “disappear” or are “overridden” in child classes. They are still there, and can be accessed by methods of the parent class.

Only when Test2 declares its own implementation for getvalue(), then Test1's private members would become inaccessible and Test2's private members would become accessible.

In other words, one could say that private members are not “virtual” (or “overridable”). They are the implementation details of the class and its methods, and are not supposed to be overridden. `Test1.__test` and `Test2.__test` are different instance variables (implemented in Python by name-mangling).

If you want the traditional OO behaviour, where a child class member overrides its parent, use a **method** in Python, Java, or a **virtual method** in C++, C#, Delphi; ***not*** private attributes. If you want to implement something without name clashes, then use private attributes.